# Quantum Phase Estimation answers distribution

Tags: quantum-algorithms, linear-algebra, quantum-phase-estimation

Suppose I have a random unitary matrix, known eigenvectors and eigenvalues. I know that exact eigenvalue for the given matrix is $0.5491617699847768+0.835716070437315j$. From here, if I'm not mistaken the phase should be equal to $5.039153255477287$ - something between $5$ and $6$. I apply the QPE algorithm for $5$ qubit scheme for eigenvalue estimation. The distribuiton of the estimated phases is in the image below.

Question: why the distribution is not concentrated around 5 and 6 only? How to interpret this distibution? If I take the math expectation (equals to $13.380000000000003$), devide it on $2^n$, where $n$ in the number of qubits for eigenvalue etimation, add $2\pi i$ and exponentiate, again I get the value (equals to $-0.87057047+0.49204375j$) **not** close to the real eigenvalue

UPD

- added [matrix](https://github.com/UralmashFox/qpe_stack/blob/main/matrix.npy) and the [eigenvector](https://github.com/UralmashFox/qpe_stack/blob/main/vector.npy);
- compressed scheme to 3 qubits for eigenvalue estimation;
- added [script](https://github.com/UralmashFox/qpe_stack/blob/main/main.ipynb) for the circuit execution

[image]

Comment: This does not look like a correct distribution for phase estimation algorithm. The phase for your value is actually around $0.9894$, or $0.15747\cdot 2\pi$. Are you sure your eigenvector is correct? Is there noise in your computation?

Comment: In the question I used my own implementation of QPE. Now I checked using qiskit and got the same distribution as a result. By the way, how did you get $0.9894$? If the eigenvalue is $eig = e^{2\cdot \pi \cdot i \cdot \frac{p}{2^n}}$, where $p$ is a phase and $n$ - number of qubits for the eigenvalue estimation, then the phase equals to $p = \frac{\ln{eig}\cdot 2^n}{2\cdot \pi i} = 5.039153255477287$ (updated value in the question)

Comment: 5.039... is correct, I was referring to the phase in radians. I'll try to check the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doublecheck your inverse QFT circuit. I get a distribution similar to yours if I put QFT instead of its inverse in the second part of the phase estimation algorithm. If the correct inverse QFT is used, the distribution is very concentrated around 5.

Here is Qiskit code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
from numpy import pi

qreg_phi = QuantumRegister(1, 'phi')
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(5, 'q')
creg_c = ClassicalRegister(5, 'c')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_phi, qreg_q, creg_c)

theta = 5.039153255477287 * pi / 16

# Prepare |1> in qreg_phi
# |1> is the eigenvector of p(theta)
circuit.x(qreg_phi[0])

# Start phase estimation for U = p(theta)

# Hadamard
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])
circuit.h(qreg_q[3])
circuit.h(qreg_q[4])

# Apply controlled U's
circuit.cp(theta, qreg_q[0], qreg_phi[0])
circuit.cp(2 * theta, qreg_q[1], qreg_phi[0])
circuit.cp(4 * theta, qreg_q[2], qreg_phi[0])
circuit.cp(8 * theta, qreg_q[3], qreg_phi[0])
circuit.cp(16 * theta, qreg_q[4], qreg_phi[0])

# Uncompute QFT
circuit.h(qreg_q[4])

circuit.cp(-pi / 2, qreg_q[4], qreg_q[3])
circuit.h(qreg_q[3])

circuit.cp(-pi / 4, qreg_q[4], qreg_q[2])
circuit.cp(-pi / 2, qreg_q[3], qreg_q[2])
circuit.h(qreg_q[2])

circuit.cp(-pi / 8, qreg_q[4], qreg_q[1])
circuit.cp(-pi / 4, qreg_q[3], qreg_q[1])
circuit.cp(-pi / 2, qreg_q[2], qreg_q[1])
circuit.h(qreg_q[1])

circuit.cp(-pi / 16, qreg_q[4], qreg_q[0])
circuit.cp(-pi / 8, qreg_q[3], qreg_q[0])
circuit.cp(-pi / 4, qreg_q[2], qreg_q[0])
circuit.cp(-pi / 2, qreg_q[1], qreg_q[0])
circuit.h(qreg_q[0])

# Swap qubits
circuit.swap(qreg_q[0], qreg_q[4])
circuit.swap(qreg_q[1], qreg_q[3])

circuit.reset(qreg_phi)
circuit.measure(qreg_q, creg_c)
```

UPD. Here is an example with arbitrary number of qubits

```
def QPE(U, phi, n):
    p = U.num_qubits
    qreg_phi = QuantumRegister(p, 'phi')
    qreg_q = QuantumRegister(n, 'q')
    
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_phi, qreg_q)
    
    circuit.initialize(phi, qreg_phi)
    
    circuit.h(qreg_q)
    
    for i in range(n):
        circuit.append(U.power(2**i).control(1), [qreg_q[i], qreg_phi])
    
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            circuit.cp(-pi / 2**(i - j), qreg_q[n - 1 - j], qreg_q[n - 1 - i])
        circuit.h(qreg_q[n - i - 1])
    
    circuit.swap(qreg_q[:n//2], qreg_q[-1:-(n//2)-1:-1])
    
    return circuit

theta = 5.039153255477287 * pi / 16
U = PhaseGate(theta)

n = 5

circuit = QPE(U, [0.0, 1.0], n)
qreg_q = circuit.qregs[1]
creg_x = ClassicalRegister(n, 'x')
circuit.add_register(creg_x)
circuit.measure(qreg_q, creg_x)
```

Comment: Yep, answer from this script gives more intuitive results. I added script that I used in my approach (from yours one), egenvector and entry matrix. The script still does not provide me answer close to what I see using your approach.

Comment: As far as I see, your vector is not an eigenvector.

Comment: The piece of code prints that the given vector coincide with eigenvector:


`vec_in_file = np.load('vector.npy')
U = np.load('matrix.npy')
eigs_u, vecs_u = np.linalg.eig(U)
vecs_u[0] == vec_in_file`

Comment: `np.linalg.eig` gives the eigenvectors as columns of a matrix, so you need `vecs_u[:,0]` instead of `vecs_u[0]`.

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot, now it works with a remark: you use $\pi / 16 $. As I understand this is  $\pi/2^{n-1}$ where $n$ is a number of qubits for phase estimation (5 qubits in your case). So, for the 3 qubit case I applied $repetitions = 4$ for [3 qubit case](https://github.com/UralmashFox/qpe_stack/blob/main/main.ipynb).
1. Am I right that for 5 qubit case I should write $repetitions = 16$?
2. The main question is still remain: if the phase is between 5 and 6, why the distribution is not concentrated around 5 and 6 only?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, for 5 qubits you'll need to start from `repetitions = 1` and loop 5 times, so it goes `1,2,4,8,16`. The final distribution is not supported only on 5 and 6 because it's basically an inverse discrete fourier transform of a vector which has non-integer frequency. It will have maximum around 5, but it needs small corrections in all other frequencies. The exact distribution and some estimates are computed for example in https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309, §3.4.

Comment: Then why in your case for 5 qubit case you used theta/16
? And how to automotize the choise of the repetition for n
 qubit case?

Comment: I used phase rotation with theta*16, which is the same as 16-fold repetition of phase rotation with theta. So in my code it also goes 1,2,4,8,16.

I added an example of a general construction.

Comment: Note that in your current code you are basically estimating phase of $U^4$ and find that it's around $5/4 \pi$. If you run it for $U$, you'll get the distriibution around $1$, which means the phase is around $1/4 \pi$. If you increase to 5 bits, you get a better estimate of $5/16 \pi$.

Comment: Thank you a lot, finally I fixed the code and have the misinterpreted theoretiacal part that I never noticed before. But is there an intuition of what the final distribution will be? I mean the probability to have $4$ is *0.002*, to have $5$ is *0.995*, and $6$ with probability *0.003*. Why the probabilities are exatly these? Not like $3$ with *0.001*, $4$ with *0.001*, $5$ with *0.995*, $6$ with *0.002* and$7$ with *0.001* or something like this